# Jquery keyup event is not working for dynamicaly added id attribute

Tags: jquery, keyup

The `keyup` event is not working for dynamically added id attribute. My code,

**HTML**

```
<div id="more-package-div" class="more-package-area">
    <input type="text" name="package_weight[]" id="package_weight_0" placeholder="Package weight" class="package_weight">
</div>
<div id="extra-packages"></div>
<a href="#" id="add-more-package">Add more package</a>
```

**JQUERY**

```
var count = 1;
var i = 0;
$('#add-more-package').on('click', function(){
    $('#extra-packages').append($('#more-package-div').html());
    $('#package_weight_'+i).attr('id','package_weight_'+count);
    i+= 1;
    count += 1;
});

$('.package_weight').on('keyup', function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

In this case the `keyup` event is only working for the first textbox. How can I trigger the 'keyup' event for dynamically added attributes ?

This is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodvt22/x749740m/)

Comment: Use event delegation. [`$('#extra-packages').on('keyup', '.package_weight', function () {`](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/x749740m/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var count = 1;
var i = 0;
$('body').on('click','#add-more-package', function(){
    $('#extra-packages').append($('#more-package-div').html());
    $('#package_weight_'+i).attr('id','package_weight_'+count);
    i+= 1;
    count += 1;
});

$('body').on('keyup','.package_weight', function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/x749740m/2/)

Comment: Don't need to delegate the event up to the body, use static parent `#extra-packages`

Comment: @Tushar there is more ways $('body') or static parent or even $(document) ... I really didn't searching before about the deference between all of this .. but anyway all of that working with me .. I know you are a very good one in that field  .. and appreciate your comment .. and I wiil looking for the deference .. Thanks